# ¿Cómo organizar registros en unta tabla Html usando ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Necesito organizar una tabla de la siguiente manera:

`Nombre` - `Eje` - `Lider` - `Pesos` - `Calificaciones` - `Ponderado`, mediante un ciclo `foreach`, mi código es el siguiente:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.calificaciones )
    {
        <tr>
        <td>@item.nombrecolaborador</td>
        <td>@item.ejecolaborador</td>
        <td>@item.lider</td>
        <td>
            @item.peso%
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.calificacion
        </td>
        <td>
            @string.Format("{0:F3}", item.ponderado)
        </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Mi controlador:

```
ViewBag.calificaciones = (from p in db.Objectives
                      join o in db.CalificarColaboradors on p.id equals o.id_objetivo
                      join f in db.Collaborators on o.codigo_colaborador equals f.codigo
                      select new calificaciones {
                          peso = p.Peso_Objetivo,
                          calificacion = o.calificacion,
                          nombrecolaborador = f.nombres,
                          ejecolaborador = f.eje_funcional,
                          lider = f.lider,
                          ponderado = (p.Peso_Objetivo * o.calificacion / 100)
                      }).ToList();
```

Actualmente me imprime los resultados de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesitaria verlos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me explico de mejor manera, necesito que por cada colaborador me imprima los pesos de manera horizontal y después de esos me imprima las calificaciones y así mismo el ponderado tal como se muestra en la imagen, porque actualmente me está imprimiendo todo de manera vertical y fuera de eso me trae el nombre tantas veces exista un registro.

Si necesitan que suba algo más, quedo atento.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62043/discussion-on-question-by-bygroxd-como-organizar-registros-en-unta-tabla-html-u).

Answer (score 1):

Cambiar la parte de tablas por divs, ellos si permiten ser más dinámicos. Tu te encargas de los estilos, pero con ellos si se pueden dar columnas distintas.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        @for (int i = 1; i<=V iewBag.calificaciones.Lenght; i++) { 
            if(ViewBag.calificaciones[i].nombrecolaborador !=V iewBag.calificaciones[i + 1].nombrecolaborador) { 
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    @ViewBag.calificaciones[i].nombrecolaborador
                </div>
               <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    @ViewBag.calificaciones[i].ejecolaborador
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                   @ViewBag.calificaciones[i].lider
               </div>
              for (int j = i; j <=t ope + i ; j++) { 
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    @ViewBag.calificaciones[i].peso%
                </div>
             } 
             for (int j = i; j <=t ope + i ; j++) { 
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                  @ViewBag.calificaciones[i].calificacion%
               </div>
            } 
            for (int j = i; j <=t ope + i ; j++) { 
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    @ViewBag.calificaciones[i].ponderado%
               </div>
           } 
       }
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

> - Remplaza table u tbody con div class="container"
> - Remplaza tr con div class="row"
> - Remplaza td con div class="col-ww-nn"
>
>   - Donde WW es el dispositivo width (xs, sm, md, lg)
>   - Donde nn es un número del 1-12 de porcentage para las columnas    (dividido en 12)

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, veo que entendiste perfectamente lo que necesito, sin embargo no se porque tu codigo no me funciona en el razor

Comment: Debe ser debido a que las tablas no se pueden renderizar debido que no todos tendrán el mismo número de columnas.

Comment: no sera porque faltan las @? ya estoy intentando

Comment: revisa muy bien todo que lo escribí a memoria, me avisas

Comment: Hola, no me funciona tu respuesta la logica esta bien como la necesito pero pues no logro hacerla funcionar

Comment: Es más, no lo hagas tan complicado, imprime una tabla por cada registro; ya que sí el número de columnas no son el mismo, la tabla no se creará.

Comment: hablas de una fila por cada registro, como lo tengo actualmente?

Comment: No, de una tabla por cada persona. Sería con la misma lógica pero en agregando las partes de la tabla completa.

Comment: Hola, pasa me piden todos los datos aparezcan en una sola tabla para exportarlo a excel, pero es esa misma logica y organizacion que usaste tu.

Comment: Entonces déjame internar otra cosa

Comment: Dale muchas gracias

Comment: Intenta con está opción

Comment: Actualizaste tu respuesta?

Comment: sí, es distinta

Comment: Dice que el nombre tope no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62029/discussion-between-bygroxd-and-aaron-romero).

Answer (score 1):

> necesito que por cada colaborador me imprima los pesos de manera
>   horizontal y despues de esos me imprima las calificaciones y asi mismo
>   el ponderado tal como se muestra en la imagen, porque actualmente me
>   esta imprimiendo todo de manera vertical

La respuesta de [JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86224/38468) te puede ayudar con eso. El lo hace exactamente asi.

> fuera de eso me trae el nombre tantas veces exista un registro.

Porque tienes que hacer un distintic por nombre utilizando un `GroupBy`:

```
ViewBag.calificaciones = (from p in db.Objectives
                      join o in db.CalificarColaboradors on p.id equals o.id_objetivo
                      join f in db.Collaborators on o.codigo_colaborador equals f.codigo
                      select new calificaciones {
                          peso = p.Peso_Objetivo,
                          calificacion = o.calificacion,
                          nombrecolaborador = f.nombres,
                          ejecolaborador = f.eje_funcional,
                          lider = f.lider,
                          ponderado = (p.Peso_Objetivo * o.calificacion / 100)


                       })
            .GroupBy(x=>x.nombrecolaborador)
            .ToList()
            .Select(x=> x.First())
```

Hay no te repetira los nombres.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62016/discussion-between-bygroxd-and-einer).

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el resultado de los datos esten bien solo debes agregar un `colspan` para agrupar las columnas, te colocare el ejemplo a continuacion

```html
<table border="1">
      <tr>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Eje</td>
          <td>Lider</td>
          <td colspan ="3">Pesos %</td>
      </tr>
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.calificaciones )
      {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.nombrecolaborador</td>
          <td>@item.ejecolaborador</td>
          <td>@item.lider</td>
          <td>@item.peso%</td>
          <td>@item.calificacion</td>
          <td>@string.Format("{0:F3}", item.ponderado)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo no da solucion alguna a mi problema.